# Track users over Cross browser for analytics

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, cross-browser

I want to track users over cross browsers without login option to perform efficient web analytics. I went through flash cookies, but they don't sound promising! Is there any other way to identify users over cross browsers?

Comment: Including when they switch between their home computer, work computer, and mobile device?    You could do that if you have them sign in.

Comment: I think you want something like Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics has this very useful feature called "Universal Analytics" that allows Cross-Device-Tracking, and thus Cross-Browser-Tacking. I am afraid that this only works if you let your user sign in, because this is actually what enables GA to recognize a user once he visits your website from a different device/browser, and GA will then show him as one unique visitor in the reports.

Actually, "Log In" is only a name for something the user does on your website to be recognized later. You could, for example, let the user enter an email address without a password and, when he does so on the next device/browser, this would be enough to recognize him. Anyway, the user would not (without further customization of the software/CMS you are using) get back his shopping basket, his wishlist or whatever, which would render this feature pretty useless in my eyes.

For further information, there is a [great blogpost by Google's Avinash Kaushik](http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/universal-analytics-implementation-tips-strategy-tactics/#useriedoverride) on Universal Analytics, and also on this very feature.